# Linux - Avoinding x server message when running .exe with wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exe, wine

I'm trying to run a .exe file (that uses some other .dll files) with wine, in Ubuntu 11.04, command line, but i get an error regarding the x server not being started and that a window is being created (i attached a screenshot).

When I run it normally (normal ubuntu boot, x server running) everything is ok, but actually, no window is displayed, which is normal because no window is needed for the program to run. So I just want to know if there is a way to avoid that: somehow simulating that the x server is open or to set $DISPLAY in some way to "fool" the program.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use Xvfb.

```
Xvfb :1 &
DISPLAY=:1 wine ...
```